# How to force update web app in deployment nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a web app that's live and when we make changes I have to force refresh the app to see those changes from our production server `command+shift+R`.

What's the right way to let the client browser know that an update has happened and to make a new request for the application?  Is the correct way to just let the browser handle that through it's internal invalidation?

I'm having a hard time finding any resources (I probably don't know the right vocabulary here to search it correctly). Is this a problem I should be trying to solve?

Comment: i think you can trigger the refresh of all app or its parts using web sockets

Comment: Services workers would work quite well for this - https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#available-and-activated-updates

Comment: Thank you! I think service workers are exactly what I need